# Using word function in makefile with variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'd like to make a custom function that get the $3 as indx from series $1 and keyword $2.
So I checked below one works well.

```
define get_indx
         @echo $(words $1)
         for n in $(shell seq 1 $(words $1)) ;\
         do \
                 echo $$n ;\
        done
endef

NLIST:= AA BB CC
$(call get_indx,$(NLIST),BB,indx)
```

But below does not work.
It says '*** non-numeric first argument to `word' function: '$n'.  Stop.'

```
define get_indx
       @echo $(words $1)
       for n in $(shell seq 1 $(words $1)) ;\
       do \
               echo $$n ;\
               echo $(word $$n, $1) ;\          
       done
NLIST:= AA BB CC
$(call get_indx,$(NLIST),BB,indx)
```

How can I access n or how can I convert to numeric?

Comment: The function `index-of` in [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-index-ofwordlist) returns the first index of a string in a list, all in pure `make` programming, i.e. working without a shell call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to create a custom function to get index from the list, I don't think you will be able to get it out as a parameter as all parameters to a function are *in* only. You can make your function output a text, which you can then assign to a variable, like so:

```
$ cat Makefile
NLIST := AA BB CC

# $1 - list to check
# $2 - element to find
# returns - index of element
define get_index
$(sort $(eval index_count :=) \
$(foreach word,$(1), \
  $(eval index_count := $(index_count) x) \
  $(if $(findstring $(word),$(2)),$(words $(index_count)))) \
)
endef

bb_index := $(call get_index,$(NLIST),BB)
$(info >$(bb_index)<)
$(info >$(call get_index,$(NLIST),CC)<)
$(info >$(call get_index,$(NLIST),AA)<)
```

The idea here is that we use a list as a counter. For every word from original list we increment the counter by adding another value to the counter list. The actual value is not important as the only thing that matters is the number of elements in the counter list. If we hit an interesting value, we output number of elements in the counter list, which represents the index at which the element was found. This output can then be stored in a variable as usual. The `$(sort)` function is only for getting rid of extra spaces.

This approach might need to be made more complex if needed depending on the circumstances (whether values may repeat etc.).

Output:

```
$ make
>2<
>3<
>1<
```

Comment: Really really great answer for me. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Getting rid of extra spaces is usually done with `strip`

Answer (score 0):

`$(word ...)` is substituted before the for loop is executed, meaning variable `n` does not exist during substitution. You might want to pass `--warn-undefined-variables` to your make invocation when debugging, think it' would've been caught in this case.

As for solution I'd look into exchanging `$(word ...)` with a shell equivalent. Might be a good idea to wrap it all in a script rather than using `define` blocks.